# Php Multidimensional array extraction

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have this multi dimensional array that came from cURL api:

```
  Array
(
    [status] => 200
    [message] => Success
    [info] => Array
        (
            [NewRegUsers] => 0
            [TotRegUsers] => 6
            [shows] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [keyword] => BANANA
                            [entries] => 1
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [keyword] => CHRISTMAS
                            [entries] => 1
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [keyword] => CONCERT
                            [entries] => 1
                        )

                    [3] => Array
                        (
                            [keyword] => EXTRA
                            [entries] => 1
                        )



                )

        )

)
```

I'm trying to get the values of **NewRegUsers**,**TotRegUsers** and the values in `[shows]` and get the keyword and entries. I used this code :

```
foreach($data['info'] as  $value)
    { 
        foreach ($value  as $item){

            $shows .= ' <tr>
                        <td class="col1">'.$x.'. '.$item['keyword'].'</th>
                        <td>'.$item['entries'].'</td>
                    </tr>';
            $x ++ ;
        }

    }
```

I'm still puzzled with arrays. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data you want is nested 2 levels deep. For that you need 2 keys as in: `$data['info']['shows']`.

That gives you another array of arrays, which you can iterate using a normal `foreach`.

I have always found that this sort of thing is easier if you:

- create an array to take the items, and join the array at the end
- use `sprintf` to insert your data, as it is more readable.

Below is a sample of how it would work:

```
$shows=array();
$tr='<tr><td class="col1">%s</th><td>%s</td></tr>';
foreach($data['info']['shows'] as $item) {
    $shows[]=sprintf($tr,$item['keyword'],$item['keyword']);
}
$shows=implode('',$shows);
```

Comment: bro this code works fine. but how will i get the [NewRegUsers]  and [TotRegUsers] ?

Answer (score 0):

You almost had it. I would do it in this manner:

```
foreach($data['info'] as  $info)
{
    $NewRegUsers = $info['NewRegUsers'];
    $TotRegUsers = $info['TotRegUsers'];

    foreach ($info['shows']  as $k => $show){
        $shows .= ' <tr>
                        <td class="col1">'.$k.'. '.$show['keyword'].'</th>
                        <td>'.$show['entries'].'</td>
                    </tr>';
    }

}
```